# Что означает "в лучших 8% в этом году"?

Tags: поддержка, faq

Скажите, пожалуйста, что значит эта надпись в профиле?

И еще: когда я нажимаю на эту надпись в профиле, выходит список участников. Дается какая-то позиция (rank) и какое-то изменение (change). Для чего этот список и что он означает? Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В текущем году вы набрали 2807 очков уважения/репутации. Это ставит вас на 5-е место в табеле: впереди Людмила (5316 за год), slava1947 (3979), Vera (3965), и Alex_ander (2913).

5-е место выражается в процентах как "лучшие 8%", где в подсчёте участвуют только пользователи с не менее чем 200 очками (их на сайте 67).  То есть, 8% от 67 это примерно 5.

Сайт отслеживает такую статистику просто из спортивного интереса. Если она неинтересна, её можно игнорировать.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо!!